# Make SQL query from four table

Tags: mysql, sql

My database have got 4 table :

**users**

- id
- username

**images**

- id
- user_id
- image

**user_follow**

- user_id
- user_follow

**commentaries**

- image_id
- text

I try to make a query to get all my and my friends pictures
1) row must be shown only if user have picture in "images" table
2) only image from me and my friends (depending on "user_follow" table)
3) count commentaries for each picture

my query is:

```
SELECT u.username as user, i.image as user_image, p.image, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(p.date) as date, COALESCE ( imgcount.cnt, 0 ) as comments
FROM users u              
LEFT JOIN user_follow f ON u.id = f.follow_id
LEFT JOIN images p ON p.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN images i ON i.id = (SELECT b.id FROM images AS b where p.user_id = b.user_id ORDER BY b.id DESC LIMIT 1)
LEFT JOIN (SELECT image_id, COUNT(*) as cnt FROM commentaries GROUP BY image_id  ) imgcount ON p.id = imgcount.image_id
WHERE f.user_id = 3 OR p.user_id = 3       
ORDER BY p.date DESC
```

Commentaries count of each image sql line works fine in this query

```
LEFT JOIN (SELECT image_id, COUNT(*) as cnt FROM commentaries GROUP BY image_id  ) imgcount ON p.id = imgcount.image_id
```

*in this line I try to get user his last upload image as avatar from "images" table*

```
   LEFT JOIN images i ON i.id = (SELECT b.id FROM images AS b where p.user_id = b.user_id ORDER BY b.id DESC LIMIT 1)
```

This query dot not return result correctly because  it show my friends who do not have pictures and something is not good with my own pictures (in database I have 2 row with my user_id : 3 ) but sql return 4

Comment: I've removed the minor bit of PHP you had around the main query - since this is about SQL syntax, including PHP wrapper code and tags is inappropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, it seems like you've made this a lot more complex than it needs to be. The reason you are getting records for your friends without pictures is because you are using a LEFT JOIN. Change that to an INNER JOIN and you will only get the records that match the join condition.

I think you are looking for something like the following.  You'll need to make a few tweaks but hopefully this helps.

```
SELECT u.username as user, i.image as user_image, count(*) as comments
FROM users u              
INNER JOIN user_follow f ON u.id = f.follow_id
INNER JOIN images p ON p.user_id = u.id
INNER JOIN commentaries c ON c.image_id = p.id
WHERE u.user_id = 3
GROUP BY u.username, i.image;
```